# How to get PicoCLI to interpret next item as flag and not string

Tags: java, command-line, picocli

I'm having a problem trying to get the [PicoCLI library](https://picocli.info) in Java to interpret the next position after a certain flag to be a string, and not another flag.

Say for example I have the following command:

```bash
$ my-cli -t -b -b "some value" my-file.txt
```

What I want is for the library to interpret the above as the following:

```
t: the string "-b"
b: the string "some value"
```

I should note that using `-t "-b"` is ***not*** an option. Currently the library returns the following error when running the program:

> Expected parameter for option '-t' but found '-b'

These are my definitions for the `-t` and `-b` parameters:

```java
@Option(names = "-b")
String bOption;

@Option(names = "-t", arity = "1..*")
public void checkTOption(List<String> values) {
  if (values != null && !values.isEmpty()) {
    tOption = values.get(values.size() - 1);
  }
}
```

Given the definition above, `-t` can also be specified multiple times, but only the last value is used. For example, these are equivalent commands:

```bash
$ my-cli -t a -t b -b "some string" -t c my-file.txt
$ my-cli -t c -b "some string" my-file.txt
```

Comment: I'd interpret `-t -b -b` as 3 flags, if the second `-b` should be a string I'd expect `-t "-b" -b`. Why is this not an option?

Comment: @Thomas Generally, double quotes are parsed by the shell, and do not occur in the actual arguments passed to the program (unless explicitly escaped)

Comment: Exactly. What I meant was that it's not an option for the user to pass `-t "-b"` to explicitly make it a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the PicoCLI documentation, section [Option Names or Subcommands as Option Values](https://picocli.info/#_option_names_or_subcommands_as_option_values).

There are in theory three options:

1. Quote the parameter (like suggested by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) in the comments). You'll need to escape the double quotes according to the requirements of your shell:

   ```bash
   $ my-cli -t \"-b\" -b "some value" my-file.txt
   ```
2. Enable the option `setAllowOptionsAsOptionParameters` on `CommandLine`. However, given the arity of `-t` is `1..*`, this would consume all following options, and therefor is not an option in your case.
3. Write a custom parameter consumer (see details in the documentation). I don't think it would be easy to solve the ambiguity of your example with that though (which is also why PicoCLI doesn't allow it anymore by default).

Comment: Thank you Mark! The `setAllowOptionsAsOptionParameters` did the trick. And you're right also about the `arity`; it should have been just `1` since the `-t` option only ever needs / takes one parameter.

Comment: @ScottCrooks The fact that your current implementation uses `checkTOption` to take the last item, suggests it was an intentional design (maybe for backwards compatibility). Not knowing the greater context of this, I would recommend that you proceed with caution.